# Class constructor/function syntax with curly braces around parameter list

Tags: javascript, class, constructor, arguments, ecmascript-6

I've recently seen this code:

```js
class Foo {
  constructor({
    a,
    b,
    c = []
  }) {
    this.a = a;
    this.b = b;
    this.c = c;
    console.log(this);
  }
}
const foo = new Foo({
  a: 1,
  b: 2
});
```

But I've never seen parameters defined with curly braces wrapping the parameter names. My linter complains about it, but the code works fine and so I assume that it is valid as it executes without error.

I've read the MDN docs about, [class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes), [constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/constructor) and [default arguments](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Default_parameters). However, I do not see this pattern described anywhere (maybe I missed it?).

What is it I'm looking for, does this pattern have a name, or is it described somewhere?

Comment: Yes, I will improve it if I know what needs improving.

Comment: It is "parameter destructuring".

Comment: Not the downvoter, but the question could have been improved by not being asked. I know it's a little hard to Google for this kind of thing, but "stack overflow curly brackets in function parameter list" worked for me. Also, if you consider yourself a semi-professional JS developer, I really recommend going through a list of all the new ES6 features, of which there are several, such as [this one](http://es6-features.org/#ParameterContextMatching).

Comment: I tried several searches and just couldn't find it. It seemed reasonable to ask what it was that I was looking at via example. Thanks. Perhaps I should delete the question?

Comment: @torazaburo Javascript is something that I do for a little fun in my spare time. I'm not a programmer. Usually I can find and read everything new. It was just one of those times that I was falling flat on my face at every turn.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is **[parameter destructuring](http://www.2ality.com/2015/01/es6-destructuring.html)**.

However, in this case, you could simply do

```
class Foo {
  constructor(opts) {
    Object.assign(this, {c: []}, opts);
    console.log(this);
  }
}

const foo = new Foo({
  a: 1,
  b: 2
});
```

You should find some kind of "es6" flag for your linter to make it happy.

Comment: Thanks. I was guessing that it was similar, but didn't know what it was called. I guess that I need to update my linter as I already have the flag set.

Comment: `Object.assign` is the way to go here. A little shorter if you put the `c` in an object in the same call `Object.assign(this, {c: []}, opts);`, though likely at the cost of an extra allocation.

Comment: I wonder if this has any impact on optimizations. Some engines have optimizations available when they're able to statically determine all the properties the object will have. It's possible that they could try to figure it out from the call site(s).

Answer (score 2):

> But I've never seen arguments defined like this before.

That's destructuring, just used on the arguments.

I couldn't find a good reference, but I believe thats an ES6 feature. What it does is decompose an object argument into individual variables and assigning the values of the properties with the same name to the variables.

It's similar to doing:

```
class Foo {
  constructor(obj) {
    this.a = obj.a;
    this.b = obj.b;
    this.c = obj.c || [];
    console.log(this);
  }
}
```

Comment: Actually, it's an ES6 feature.

Comment: Described here I think: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Pulling_fields_from_objects_passed_as_function_parameter

Comment: Thanks. I was having a hard time searching for what I was looking at.